# Remove auto appearing BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to remove the auto appearing BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here is the following image which I am getting while selecting New Query to write.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have "SSMS Tools Pack" installed ?

at some times that the "New Query Template" option had somehow been enable and configured.

I think if you disabled it then this should have been removed

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much. I got it.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely because you have SSMS tools installed.

SSMS Tools > New Query Template > Options > Disable

From SSMS Tools site: http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=13

Props: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1206272-391-1.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. But unfortunately I need to accept the answer which comes first and too correct. But +1 for sure.